# Prototype design pattern example (c++)

Tags: design-patterns, prototype-pattern

I am learning Prototype design pattern and get confused from an example represented on [this article](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype/cpp/1) by [sourcemaking](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype).

```
class Stooge
{
public:
   virtual void slap_stick() = 0;
   virtual Stooge* clone() = 0;
};

class Larry : public Stooge
{
public:
   void slap_stick()
   {
      cout << "Larry: poke eyes\n";
   }
   Stooge*   clone() { return new Larry; }   
};
class Moe : public Stooge
{
public:
   void slap_stick()
   {
      cout << "Moe: slap head\n";
   }
   Stooge*   clone() { return new Moe; }   
};
class Curly : public Stooge
{
public:
   void slap_stick()
   {
      cout << "Curly: suffer abuse\n";
   }
   Stooge*   clone() { return new Curly; }
};

class Factory
{
public:
   static Stooge* make_stooge( int choice );
private:
   static Stooge* s_prototypes[4];
};

Stooge* Factory::s_prototypes[] = {0, new Larry, new Moe, new Curly};

Stooge* Factory::make_stooge( int choice )
{
   return s_prototypes[choice]->clone();
}

int main()
{
   vector roles;
   int    choice;

   while (true)
   {
      cout << "Larry(1) Moe(2) Curly(3) Go(0): ";
      cin >> choice;
      if (choice == 0)
         break;
      roles.push_back(Factory::make_stooge( choice ) );
   }

   for (int i=0; i < roles.size(); ++i)
      roles[i]->slap_stick();
   for (int i=0; i < roles.size(); ++i)
      delete roles[i];
}
```

According to description Prototype Design Pattern

- Specify the kinds of objects to create using a prototypical instance, and create new objects by copying this prototype.

According to [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Prototype.aspx). The prototype design pattern is a design pattern that is used to instantiate a class by copying, or cloning, the properties of an existing object.

As far as I know, the normal way of copying a class is to use copy constructors,  overload operator=, or implement clone function to instantiate a new object by copying all of the properties of an existing object.

On the example above, I do not see how it achieves creating new objects by copying the prototype, as nor copy constructors, neither overload operator=, or appropriate clone function defined.

So can I assume that this is not an implementation of prototype design pattern? Or maybe I am wrong on my assumptions and do not understand this example?

**EDITED:** As @[songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309790/songyuanyao) mentioned

> In the example, it's creating new objects newly, without copying anything

So I am considering above example as NOT appropriate example of prototype pattern as it DO NOT represent main target of prototype pattern.

Comment: In the example, it's creating new objects newly, without copying anything.

Comment: Yes exactly, as You mention "it's creating new objects newly, without copying anything" so it isn't represent the main idea of prototype design pattern

Comment: Using copy ctor might make more sense. Such as `return new Larry(*this);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it is not necessary to clone an object calling a method on it, it could be perfectly possible you have a `Manager` or `Factory` that have a method used to clone the object i.e:

```
Object Factory::clone( Object &){

}
```

In addition, it is true you can use a Copy Constructor, but the downside of **Copy Constructor is that it works only for Concrete Classes**. If, for good design decisions, you offer only the object API (Interface/ Pure virtual) to users, then you cannot use a copy constructor on client side, so if the intended usage is cloning an item you can resolve that by adding a `Clone` method

```
class BaseVirtualClass{
public:
    virtual int foo() = 0;
    virtual BaseVirtualClass * clone() = 0;
    virtual ~BaseVirtualClass(){}
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseVirtualClass{
    int state;
public:
    DerivedClass(int a):state(a){}
    DerivedClass( const DerivedClass & other)
        : state(other.state){}
    int foo(){ // override
        return state;
    }

    BaseVirtualClass * clone(){ //override
         // I'm using copy constructor here, but hidden from user
         return new DerivedClass( *this);
    }
};
```

usage:

```
BaseVirtualClass * obj = factory.createObject();
BaseVirtualClass * clone = obj->clone();
```

Also sometimes you want do that through factories:

```
BaseVirtualClass * obj = factory.createObject();
BaseVirtualClass * clone = factory.clone(obj);
```

**NOTE:** Apart fixing the missing copy constructor when you offer only pointers to abstract classes, the `Clone` method have the clear intent to copy an object state creating a [Deep Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy), without having to write boiler plate code to re-create the object in that particular state. When the responsibility of creating the object is not of the object (because you have to use a factory with a custom allocator or other complex dependencies) then the clone method is moved to the Factory.

---

**EDIT:**

The code sample the questioner found on internet seems to me an edge case.
The objects are technically clones (they have no state, apart the type, and hence they have the same state), but I do not find that to be a good example of Prototype pattern:

1. I want to use the Prototype pattern when there are complex objects with **interesting state** that needs to be *replicated in some way*.
2. The most important part is copying of the state, so also the internal implementation should be **explicit about that** (leaving an object with the same state implicit may be unclear for internal documentation purposes)

Comment: Yes, thanks for explanations. As the main target of prototype design pattern is to create new instance by cloning existed one (either using copy constructor or any other method), and the example I posted DO NOT do that, and just creates new objects, So I consider that as NOT appropriate example of prototype pattern as it DO NOT represent main target of prototype pattern.

Comment: I see, the code you found on the NET is not a good example to learn from, but technically it do not break the "clone contract": infact it is creating a new object wich is still a clone (the object **has no state**, apart the type, and hence creating a new object yields another object with same state, think it as a bad implementation). of course that's a corner case wich may never happens in a real application :) If the code example I created is enough for you could you accept it? thanks :)

Comment: Yes, this comment in addition to your answer seems answering to my question. So maybe you can add this comment to your answer and I will accept :)

Comment: Ok I added that to the answer :)

Comment: Please read my below comment and reply if you know the complete detail about this pattern.

Comment: @SagarGohel I see no other comment, What you want to know :) ?

Comment: In above example is it replacing the object in s_prototypes variable? by clone method??? if yes then what will happen to existing object ,the one which gets replaced...will it create memory leak???

If no then how "new" will do cloning or caching in existing object because when u use new it will completely create new object, not the existing one..  

Stooge* Factory::s_prototypes[] = {0, new Larry, new Moe, new Curly};

Stooge* Factory::make_stooge( int choice )
{
   return s_prototypes[choice]->clone();
}
@DarioOO

Comment: Sorry, What do you want to know? Prototype pattern is about creating multiple same objects with different lifetimes.

Comment: The concern here is new will completely create new object so what will happen to existing object in s_prototypes variable??? is it expected behavior???
because when u use the new in clone method then it will create new object....@DarioOO

Comment: What happens to object in `s_prototypes` variable? nothing. The purpose of the pattern is taking some existing "original object" and then duplicate it, the original is never touched. Think to a videogame, you setup a Enemy with graphics etc, then you clone it as many times as many enemies you want, but you never change the original. Infact the clone method can be `const` (as well as copy constructor)